# Static Resource is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundatio (WPF) project

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

I've been using Visual Studio Professional 2013 for a while now but this is my first time building a Windows Phone app. I create an empty Windows Phone application but this error is present in the MainPage.xaml from the very creation, together with the 18 similar ones like "Grid is not supported..." and "RowDefinition is not supported..." :/

the screen: http://ima.ge/1wssrHg

does anyone have a clue?

thanks

Comment: I just discovered that the project is built with no problems, but when deploying it's throwing these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like a Windows Phone Application solution to me.  You need to install the Windows Phone SDK to get the templates/projects.  Once you done that your Solution Explorer should look like this:

[image]

---

See how it says "Windows Phone" right next to the project name?  Your does not say anything....and I bet your `References` don't look like the screen shot as well.  My guess is you made a WPF Application by mistake.

Comment: I'm reinstalling the VS and WP8 SDK right now, I'll try your tips right away.